# Syntax for average if with OR and AND statements (example in body of Q)

Tags: excel-formula

I've come across an issue with AVERAGEIFS formula where they are unable to complete OR and AND simultaneously.

I'm working with data in the format below. I have one consistent criteria, in this example is "DF" in Column B. I have alternative criteria which can also be correct, "Dog*" or "Cat*" in Column A. In column C is the Cuteness Level.

Therefore, I am trying to work out the average cuteness level of Dogs and Cats with Vet Code DF with an Average If formula.

I've tried the following which doesn't work;

```
=AVERAGE(IF(OR(AND(A2:A17="Cat*",B2:B17="DF"),AND(A2:A17="Dog*",B2:B17="DF")),C2:C17, FALSE))
```

Can anyone please explain where I am going wrong?

Average IF
[image]

Comment: `=` doesn't work with wildcard, but you can use something like `LEFT(A2:A17,3)="Cat"` instead. You can also add `AVERAGEIF` formulas together to avoid the array formula

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out AVERAGEIFS with multiple wildcard conditions, but you can try something like:

```
= AVERAGE( IF( OR(Left(A2:A17,3)="Cat", Left(A2:A17,3)="Dog") * (B2:B17="DF"), C2:C17 ) )
```

Comment: Hi Slai, thank you for making an effort with this problem - I should have included in my real data set the variables known in this example as "Cat" and "Dog" are variable in length. In this instance I've decided to go the simple route and manually work out shared averages.